# Pause button not working in slick carousel when opened new tab and coming back to the existing tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Found jsfiddle online having same issue I am facing:

[JSfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/k6jq2ym6/6/)

Steps to reproduce:

1) click on pause

2) open new tab or go to an existing tab

3) coming back to the jsfiddle link

Auto play starts even when pause was clicked before. Not maintaining its current state when coming back from the new tab.

```
$(".slider").slick({
    autoplay: true,
    dots: true,
    pauseOnDotsHover: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000,
});

$('.pause').on('click', function() {
    $('.slider')
        .slick('slickPause')
        .slick('slickSetOption', 'pauseOnDotsHover', false);
});

$('.play').on('click', function() {
    $('.slider')
        .slick('slickPlay')
        .slick('slickSetOption', 'pauseOnDotsHover', true);
});
```

Comment: Maybe the script listens for window focus event

Answer (score 1):

I have used following code to make it work and solve my issue.

I have also stopped auto play when paused which worked perfectly.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".slider").slick({
      autoplay: true,
      dots: true,
      pauseOnDotsHover: true,
  });
  $('.pause').on('click', function() {
      $('.slider')
          .slick('slickPause')
          .slick('slickSetOption', 'pauseOnDotsHover', false)
          .slick('slickSetOption', 'autoplay', false);
  });

  $('.play').on('click', function() {
      $('.slider')
          .slick('slickPlay')
          .slick('slickSetOption', 'pauseOnDotsHover', true)
          .slick('slickSetOption', 'autoplay', true);
  });
  $('.slider').slick('slickPlay');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the script is listening for some event. Best workaround I can think of is to disable autoplay, then use $.ready to trigger a click on .play:

```
$(function() {
  $(".play").click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A valid solution to your problem is to initialize the carousel with `autoplay: false` and after that call the function `$('.slider').slick('slickPlay');` manually inside the `$( document ).ready` function to play the carousel, like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".slider").slick({
      autoplay: false,
      dots: true,
      pauseOnDotsHover: true,
  });
  $('.pause').on('click', function() {
      $('.slider')
          .slick('slickPause')
          .slick('slickSetOption', 'pauseOnDotsHover', false);
  });

  $('.play').on('click', function() {
      $('.slider')
          .slick('slickPlay')
          .slick('slickSetOption', 'pauseOnDotsHover', true);
  });
  $('.slider').slick('slickPlay');
});
```

I tested it and is working as you want. I hope that can help you.

Comment: I have followed different way, which worked , I want it to autoplay when page loads and I have posted my answer which allows both

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('.slide_home').length) {
    $('.slide_home').slick({
        arrows: true,
        dots: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 5000,
        speed: 1200,
        fade: true,
        swipe: false            
    });

    $('.slide_home .slick-dots').append('<span class="pause float-right mt-1"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-pause" style="color: #2e4486"></i></a></span>');
    $('.slide_home .slick-dots').append('<span class="play float-right mt-1 d-none"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-play" style="color: #2e4486"></i></a></span>');


    $('.pause').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.slide_home')
            .slick('slickPause')
            $('.play')
            .removeClass('d-none');
            $('.pause')
            .addClass('d-none')

    });
    
    $('.play').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.slide_home')
            .slick('slickPlay');
            $('.pause')
            .removeClass('d-none');
            $('.play')
            .addClass('d-none')
    });
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).